# Python Sympy superposition of several waves

Tags: python, math, sympy, trigonometry

We are trying to switch from Mathematica to python with sympy. Unfortunately sympy is not that mighty. One task for our students was to calculate the resulting oscillation in the form

[image: test]

from the given form

[image: test2]

I tried several common simplifying tools from sympy like simplify, trigsimp but nothing worked.
Sympy just simplifys every term like

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this task with sympy or other python modul ?

Comment: I am not sure what the goal is. I cannot provide more advice if I do not see what you have tried and what output you want. But you must note that `0.3` or `1.0` or any float written in Python is a floating point approximation to the numbers that you write. `1.0` is in fact an infinite fraction of `0.111111111...` in binary. When working with exact math, you must avoid approximations such as floats as much as possible. To do this, instead of writing `0.3`, rather write `S("0.3", rational=True)` or `S(3)/10` or `Rational(3, 10)`. Whichever you feel most comfortable.

Comment: Never mind. I understand now that you want to get from the second image to the first.

Comment: Please include formulas as plain text, rather than images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I couldn't find a way to do it automatically using SymPy. I even tried `sympy.physics.optics.waves.TWave` which seemed to be for this very thing. But after a long time of trying, I am convinced there is a bug in that code. The superposition in that code is not even associative.

So instead we solve it ourselves. We first get the expression into the form `a*sin(t) + b*cos(t)`. We then solve a simultaneous equation: `a = A * cos(c)` and `b = A * sin(c)`. Since this this can be precomputed we do so. The final answer will be `A*cos(t-c)`.

Here is the code that does this:

```py
from sympy import *

t = symbols('t', real=True)
expr = 2*sin(t+S(3)/10) + 5*cos(t + pi/4) + cos(t - S(31)/10)

d = collect(expr.expand(trig=True), [sin(t), cos(t)], evaluate=False)
a = d[sin(t)]
b = d[cos(t)]
cos_phase = atan(a/b)
amplitude = a / sin(cos_phase)
print(amplitude.evalf() * cos(t - cos_phase.evalf()))
```

Giving

```
3.50537475229229*cos(t + 0.468638709416397)
```

After plotting both graphs, they seem correct.

Note that this code above does not work for different frequencies of `t`.